# Display keypoint coordinates in OpenCV 3.1.0

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV 3.1.0 in VS2013 and what i am trying to do is using SimpleBlobDetector to detect light spots in the video captured by my webcam.

It worked, and then I planned to display the coordinates of the marked keypoints(light spots). The code I'm using is

```
vector<KeyPoint> detectKeyPoint;
Ptr<SimpleBlobDetector> sbd = SimpleBlobDetector::create(params);
sbd->detect(gray, detectKeyPoint);
cout << detectKeyPoint[0].pt.x << ", " << detectKeyPoint[0].pt.y << endl;
```

However the coordinates displayed in the console won't refresh when I tried to change the position of the flashlight. It only showed the coordinates where the light spot appeared and disappeared. Am I using the wrong commands or what?

Any help is appreciated!

The complete code of my program is here:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>  

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
//open the default camera  
VideoCapture cap(0);

//check if the camera is opened successfully  
if (!cap.isOpened())
{
    return -1;
}

vector<KeyPoint> detectKeyPoint;
KeyPoint* ppt;
Mat keyPointImage;

//![SBD] 
//set detector parameters 
SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;

//filter by area 
params.filterByArea = true;
params.minArea = 20;
params.maxArea = 2000;

//filter by circularity 
params.filterByCircularity = true;
params.minCircularity = 0.1;

//filter by convexity 
params.filterByConvexity = true;
params.minConvexity = 0.87;

//filter by inertia
params.filterByInertia = true;
params.minInertiaRatio = 0.01;

//instantiate a SBD pointer 
Ptr<SimpleBlobDetector> sbd = SimpleBlobDetector::create(params);
//create two windows showing..  
namedWindow("Original"); //the original video captured  
moveWindow("Original", 150, 300); 

namedWindow("VideoCapture"); //the video after setting threshold  
moveWindow("VideoCapture", 830, 300); 

for (;;)
{
    Mat frame, gray;
    //read every frame of the camera input  
    cap >> frame;
    if (frame.channels() == 3)
    {
        cvtColor(frame, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    }
    else
    {
        frame.copyTo(gray);
        //frame >> gray; 
    }
    //setting threshold to create binary image, using THRESH_BINARY_INVERTED  
    threshold(gray, gray, 252, 255, 1);

    //detect lightspots in the frame and store them in detectKeyPoint 
    sbd->detect(gray, detectKeyPoint);

    cout << detectKeyPoint[0].pt.x << ", " << detectKeyPoint[0].pt.y << endl;

    //mark the key points with red circles 
    drawKeypoints(frame, detectKeyPoint, keyPointImage, Scalar(0, 0, 255), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);

    //display videos  
    imshow("Original", gray);
    imshow("VideoCapture", keyPointImage);

    waitKey(30);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I think you should try to declare your vector of KeyPoint in the loop. The detect function probably just "push back" the new results behind the previous ones.

Comment: @AxelB. But the coordinates do refresh when I move the light source out of the frame and move it in again. Then I tried to declare the vector in the loop and I think what you said makes sense. But the program keeps throwing exceptions at different places, often on statement sbd->detect(gray, detectKeyPoint); I am totally confused now...